# iText inline svg not locate by coordinates

Tags: java, svg, pdf-generation, itext, vaadin

I've been trying to use batik and iText to create a PDF in my application containing an SVG graph, however I only seem to be able to find examples where the svg is located at some coordinates.  I don't want to have the image located at some coordinates however, I'm wanting it to be put into the page, preferably fit to the width of the page depending on whether it is landscape or portrait and be inline with any other content that I might add, have everything wrap around it.

Is this possible?  I'm beginning to suspect my wish that somewhere it will start behaving like HTML is going to be in vain.

Many thanks,

Andrew

p.s.I have a working JAVA class to place the SVG on the page as a template, as per this tutorial:
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=263

p.p.s.For people looking for this issue in relation to Vaadin Charts I've tagged the question as Vaadin related also, as that's what has generated my SVG.

Comment: I've got an interrim solution to this issue, I've converted the SVG to a PNG using batik, although it's not ideal, it looks a bit fuzzy, not the crisp edges and text that SVG gave me.  Any Solution to inserting an SVG would still be very welcome!